# How can you change the temporary directory?

Tags: deployment

I migrated the site from the local server to live server. But the images do not appear - the website logo and some PDFs. I've been seeing the problem could be here "Config" >> "file system" and my temporary directory is: `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php` because I need to change that. But I do not know how. if you can help me. please

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(temporary://logo_verde_maior.png): failed
>   to open stream:
>   "Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\TemporaryStream::stream_open" call failed
>   in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->moveUploadedFile() (line 81 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php).

This is error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php9al1tV' to
>   'temporary://logo_verde_maior.png' in
>   Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->moveUploadedFile() (line 81 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php). File upload error. Could
>   not move uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

In https://www.drupal.org/node/3039026 / https://www.drupal.org/node/3039255, which was introduced in Drupal 8.8.0, the ability to configure the temp directory was removed from the UI and moved to `settings.php`.

From the change record:

> The following lines are now in default.settings.php
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Temporary file path:
>  *
>  * A local file system path where temporary files will be stored. This directory
>  * must be absolute, outside of the Drupal installation directory and not
>  * accessible over the web.
>  *
>  * If this is not set, the default for the operating system will be used.
>  *
>  * @see \Drupal\Component\FileSystem\FileSystem::getOsTemporaryDirectory()
>  */
> # $settings['file_temp_path'] = '/tmp';
> ```

So, you should edit your settings file.

If your temp directory is different in your environments, you need a mechanism to handle this.  I typically use `.env` files for this, the database connection info, and some other settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the new temp folder has the required permissions in order for Drupal to read-write files/folders.

Does the browser console gives you any hints on this issue?

Also from 8.8, the path for tmp folder is being set via `settings.php`, so make sure you have this set up correctly

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't find the new temp folder

Comment: Yes i have error in the browser console:

Comment: is this one: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Then set the temp folder path in your `settings.php` file with this `$settings['file_temp_path'] = '/tmp';` and make sure the folder exists and the server has write rights there